# Overwriting NSDocument's init(contentsOf:ofType:) in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdocument

### background:

Regarding to the document-based Cocoa application, Apple suggests to override NSDocument's `init(contentsOf:ofType:)` to customize things, therefore it seems as if it's a good place to override.

> You can override this method to customize the reopening of autosaved documents.
>
> cf. [init(contentsOf:ofType:) - NSDocument | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocument/1515097-init)

However on Swift, it is actually impossible because super's `init(contentsOf:ofType:)` can't be invoked in `init(contentsOf:ofType:)` since this initializer is one of the convenience initializers.

```
convenience init(contentsOf url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws {

    try super.init(contentsOf: url, ofType: typeName)  // <- this marked as error
}
```

### what I want:

When I write document-based apps in Objective-C, I use this method, namely `initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:`, to prepare some file-related properties only for the document which opened with an existing file but not for new blank documents or resumed documents.

It cannot be simply substituted with NSDocument's `read(from:ofType)` because it will be invoked not only when document opens but also every time when the document is reloaded (e.g. Revert).

It is also not possible to do my stuff on normal `init()`, because `fileURL` property is not yet set at that moment.

```
init() {
    super.init()

    self.fileURL  // <- returns nil
}
```

I know a convenience initializer must invoke a designated initializer, but `init(contentsOf:ofType:)` is much complex and unclear to imitate super's behavior unlike `init(type:)`. ([How do I initialise a new NSDocument instance in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694877/how-do-i-initialise-a-new-nsdocument-instance-in-swift))

Something like this? (but not sure)

```
 convenience init(contentsOf url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    self.init()

    self.fileURL = url
    self.fileType = typeName
    self.fileModificationDate = (try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path))?[.modificationDate] as? Date
}
```

### question:

So, my question is: Where is the suitable point to do stuff with fileURL only once when document is opened?

### workaround 1:

For workaround, I currently override `makeDocument(withContentsOf:ofType:` of NSDocumentController subclass and create a document from original document's initializer in which `self.init(contentsOf: url, ofType: typeName)` is invoked.

### workaround 2:

The first workaround I mentioned above was not safe. I found it's better to do additional initialization in a separated function.

```
override func makeDocument(withContentsOf url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws -> NSDocument {

    let document = try super.makeDocument(withContentsOf: url, ofType: typeName)

    (document as? Document)?.additionalInit()  // call original func

    return document
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitly a shortcoming in current swift and as far as I can see discussed at Swift development. Yet, the override can be easily achieved. From Apple documentation it is clear that `read(from:, typeName)` is called and `fileURL`, `fileType` and `fileModificationDate` are set. That are a few simple calls like for example:

```
convenience init(contentsOf url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    self.init()
    try self.read(from:url, ofType:typeName)
    self.fileURL = url
    self.fileType = typeName
    self.fileModificationDate = Date()
    //methods and sets values for the fileURL, fileType, and fileModificationDate properties.
    self.undoManager?.disableUndoRegistration()
    self.initializeGroups(false)
    self.managedObjectContext?.processPendingChanges()
    self.undoManager?.enableUndoRegistration()
}
```

I am just starting an `NSPersistentDocument` subclass and for now this works well.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the "override" is not visible to NSDocumentController. So one have to override the methods of NSDocumentController as OP described and that basically the thing OP was is trying to avoid.